# Detect context with python

Tags: python

If I have the following strings:

```
str1 = 'Steel toe boots are required'
str2 = 'Steel toe considerations: required'
str3 = 'Steel toe optional'
str4 = 'Steel toe precoutions: just be careful'
str5 = 'Steel toe are optional'
str6 = 'Steel toe up to you'
str7 = 'Steel toe mandatory'
```

And any combination of different wording saying the same things differently, ie whether steel toe boots are required, and I wanted to reduce each of these strings into a bolean of True or False for a database variable. What is the best way to do this/ best library for achieving the most accurate result.

I have tried just searching the text for Steel toe and Steel toe required but thats only so accurate as the amount of information I am receiving is a lot so possible wordings can be very different.

Comment: You can feed the sentences to a [zero-shot classification model](https://discuss.huggingface.co/t/new-pipeline-for-zero-shot-text-classification/681): required / optional

Comment: @Carl_M this has nothing to do with sentiment analysis

Comment: Are you looking for a test (contains 'steel toe' ) AND (contains word in ("required",", mandatory")? Do you have enough data to elaborate the tests?

Comment: @Kendle I think that is a possibility, I just am wondering if there will be a lower margin of error using a different method. I am unsure of all the possible ways this can be listed as its for web scrapping indeed jobs descriptions and have seen many different ways to write this but not all of them. If all else fails I will resort to a test like you are describing.

Comment: I'm now thinking that my test would misinterpret "steel toed not required" :-(